# Using Data from Environment in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to use data from Global Environment in **R Markdown**. When I call a `'summary(mydata)'` it gives me this error:

> object 'mydata' not found

I got all my work in many different scripts, so that is not easy for me to create a `.R` file for each result.

So, can I call data defined on Global Environment in **R Markdown**?

Thank You.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are 2 ways to load the data `myData` to your .RMD file:

1. Don't knit your file with the Rstudio "knit" button:

   ```
   library(knitr)
   knit('your_file.Rmd')
   ```

This will take your recent environment into account and the error should be gone.

2. Store your `myData` as `"myData.RData"` and load it manually in your RMD file

   ````
   ```{r load myData, include=FALSE}
   load("myData.RData")
   ````

   If you do it this way you can use the "knit" button from RStudio.

I hope one of this ways is a good solution for you.

Comment: This does not work; I'm getting the error: 

"cannot open compressed file 'DATASET NAME.Rdata', probable reason 'No such file or directory'Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection"