# R markdown "argument is of length zero"

Tags: r, for-loop, r-markdown, markdown

Code is running fine in R, but getting an "argument is of length zero" error when I run in R Markdown. Just running a loop to split a probability output into 0 or 1 at 50%.

Looked through some similar posts but didn't find anything about issues when moving to markdown.

```
for (i in 0: (nrow(test)-1)){
  i <- i+1
  if (test$pred_basemodel[i] < 0.5){
    test$pred_basemodel[i] <- 0
  }
  else {
    test$pred_basemodel[i] <- 1
  }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: While I understand that your code is from an r-markdown document, there is nothing else in the question that suggests that fact has anything to do with it (or with markdown in general). If there is something relevant, then please include more context (within at least a reproducible portion of your Rmd document) so that we can see the context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove `i <- i+1` in the `for` loop, since `i` is the iterator which will run through `1:nrow(test)` automatically. Also, you can use `1:nrow(test)` instead of `0:(nrow(test)-1)` as the `for` loop condition, since your indexing naturally starts from `1`.

You can try the code below

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
  if (test$pred_basemodel[i] < 0.5){
    test$pred_basemodel[i] <- 0
  }
  else {
    test$pred_basemodel[i] <- 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for catching that! So this is running great in regular R, but R Markdown is throwing the same error with your code now...

Comment: @EmmaDahl do you include `test` in your markdown? like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39369090/12158757

Comment: Yep, it's just a copy-paste of my original code at this point

Comment: @EmmaDahl maybe you'd better paste more parts from your Rmarkdown code, otherwise it might be tough to know what happened